# How to use 3rd party TvProvider objects in own app?

Tags: android, android-tv

[Here we have a sample app](https://github.com/android/tv-samples/tree/master/ClassicsKotlin), what registers a channel for Android TV, [so these channels are provided on the home screen](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations-channel) by the operating system.

Assuming that content providers like Netflix, Prime etc. provide each a channel, how can I display these channels in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those `TvProvider`s are accessible by the Android system only. When you creating a channel, you need to register a provider for that channel in the system - that is what `TvProvider`s are for essentially. You hardly can display your channel in your own app in a proper way - there is no default channel UI provided by a [leanback](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/leanback) library - so that you have to create a UI for that yourself or hack around in the leanback components.

You can work only with the channels you created. You can create, update, and manage access to them - that is all. All the UI stuff and utilization of content, you have provided on channel creation, handles the Android TV system.

There is no access to other vendors `TvProvider`s and channels from within your app, and I guess there will never be.

Here is how to query all channels available in your TvProvider

```
private val CHANNELS_MAP_PROJECTION = arrayOf(
    TvContractCompat.Channels._ID,
    TvContractCompat.Channels.COLUMN_INTERNAL_PROVIDER_ID,
    TvContractCompat.Channels.COLUMN_BROWSABLE
)

context.contentResolver.query(
    TvContractCompat.Channels.CONTENT_URI,CHANNELS_MAP_PROJECTION, 
    null, null, null
)
```

[Here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tv-watchnext/blob/master/step_1/src/main/java/com/example/android/watchnextcodelab/channels/ChannelTvProviderFacade.kt) is a neat example from googlecodelabs of how to properly use TvProvider calls.

[Here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tv-watchnext/blob/master/step_1/src/main/java/com/example/android/watchnextcodelab/channels/SynchronizeChannelService.kt) is an example from the same app of how to add your channels to the TvProvider.

[Here](https://source.android.com/devices/tv) is the whole flow of how Android Tv works with Tv Providers and general [limitations](https://source.android.com/devices/tv#permissions) and possibilities descriptions

Thus you are no able to do it at all. Only apps with `signature` /`signatureOrSystem` protectionLevel will be able to use it. The only apps that use such protectionLevel are the apps vendors signs with the same key as an AOSP itself and/or placed them in a special folder - only vendors of devices can do it(or you, but only on rooted devices). What you want is impossible for the general consumer app.

Comment: What about a ContentProvider? Shouldn't I be able to 'query()' the PreviewPrograms via  'ContentResolver'?

Comment: You are able to do it, but only with your apps own TvProvider.

Comment: I thought ContentProviders are to provide data to other apps?

Comment: Yes. But you can use it inside your own app also, And we are providing our app data to other apps - to the Android TV launcher, Watch Next App, etc. What they did here is they limited usage of this particular Provider only to the Android system apps and the app inside which it was created. I think it was made due to the content licensing and/or some extended features for the particular video(interactivity, overlays, etc.). Because when you press play on a channel video it is played inside the app that provides the video. It is not played in some system default player.

Comment: Can you tell where this usage limitation is?

Comment: [Here](https://source.android.com/devices/tv) - more specififcally [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tv#permissions)

Comment: I have't checked the permission thing, when I understand of course. What do I have to change in that sample app, so I can apply the contentresolver? Remove the permission restriction?

Comment: You are no able to do it at all. Only apps with `signature `/`signatureOrSystem` protectionLevel will be able to use it. The only apps that use such protectionLevel are the apps vendors signs with the same key as an AOSP itself and/or placed them in a special folder - only vendors of devices can do it(or you, but only on rooted devices). What you want is impossible for the general consumer app.

Comment: Placed what in a special folder? The key? Rooted sounds nice, where can I look for rooted devices?

Comment: @RalfWickum these are whole other questions barely related to the original. We should resolve the current one, then create new questions and I or someone else will answer them. One post once the question answered - this is the rule.

Comment: I created a follow up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301651/how-to-access-3rd-party-tvprovider-on-rooted-device