# How to access 3rd party TvProvider on rooted device?

Tags: android-contentprovider, android-tv, android-contentresolver

My question is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65214796/5102206).

Let's assume I have an Android Tv stick, I also am the vendor. There are 3rd party apps like Netflix, Prime, etc. I want to access the channels provided via `TvProvider` or `ContentResolver`. As pointed out in one comment:

1. apps vendors signs with the same key as an AOSP itself
2. placed them in a special folder - only vendors of devices can do it
3. or you, but only on rooted devices

How are my possibilities for the options above?

Answer (score 0):

Using one of the proposed options you will be able to get all channels from the `TvProvider` inside the apps with `signature` /`signatureOrSystem` protection level. I don't know the specifics but I assume they may be different for different ROMs you may use. You will be able to retrieve the data from `TvProvider` the same way you are able to do it in your own app - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65214796/9248201) answer has links to examples from Android system app.

You will be able to render `Rows` from the data via [leanback](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/leanback) library in your own app(I don't know whether it should be a launcher or just an app). After the user by clicking on a card will enter the app that provided the content and view it there. You will not be able to view the videos inside your own app even if it is a system one because you would have to have access to the backend of the app that provided the media and that information is not stored in the `TvProvider`. The media inside a TvProvider is rather a simple link to a content page inside the other app.

There is plenty of info online about modifying ROMs, creating `signatureOrSystem` apps I cannot dive a specific link because I cannot verify its validity, because I haven't tried to do such things with `TvProvider` in specifics and Android OS in general(except for the root and disassembling and modifying already existing apps from the device vendor - also plenty info online).